# ESP32 Setting incorrect or missing a cyper for ssl

Tags: security, esp32, google-cloud-iot, arduino-esp32

I've been trying to setup ESP32 to post to Google Cloud IoT core and use the Pub/Sub core to receive/transmit messages. However, there is a very strange issue I am facing.

I have my laptop which I have been using for development. When I program the ESP32 with the laptop, it would work fine for a few number of times and then suddenly the connection with Google Cloud will break and it will say "Setting incorrect or missing a cyper for ssl".

This is very inconvenient as a lot of data is missed during this disconnect and reconnect phase.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Is there any additional info required?

Comment: Hi Ash, welcome to SO. Yes, we need your code. I'd recommend taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and looking at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Tarmo Really appreciate the guidance. I will make necessary additions to the main question.